# ng-click directive not calling controller function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-scope, html5-canvas

I am working on an ionic app, trying to use ng-click to call a function from my controller. here is the function i want to call.

```
function startSpin()
    {
        if ($scope.wheelSpinning == false)
        {
            spinWheel.animation.spins = 9;
            spinWheel.startAnimation();
            $scope.wheelSpinning = true;
        }
    }

function resetWheel()
{
    spinWheel.stopAnimation(false);
    spinWheel.rotationAngle = 0;
    spinWheel.draw();

    $scope.wheelSpinning = false;
    $scope.$apply();
}
```

what i am attempting to do here is like a wheel of fortune game and i am using winWheel.js library from this source http://dougtesting.net. In my view I want to call the startSpin() and resetWheel() functions from a button. Here is my code here.

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="300px" height="315px" style="margin: 25px">
    Canvas not supported
</canvas>
<button onClick="spinWheel.startSpin()">Spin the Wheel</button>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="spinwheel.resetWheel();">Reset</a>
```

With this it returns on the console when i click the spin button

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: spinWheel is not defined
```

and when i use the ng-click directive it has no effect, outputs nothing to the console almost like its a disabled button. I don't know what i am doing wrong here and will need some help, very much appreciated and if more info is needed will be more than glad to paste here. Thanks for the help.

note that is just part of the code in my controller.

here is the complete code for the controller

```
.controller('PlayCtrl', ["$scope", "$ionicPopup", function($scope, $ionicPopup) {
 // Create new wheel object specifying the parameters at creation time.
 var spinWheel = new Winwheel({
'numSegments' : 6,      // Specify number of segments.
'outerRadius' : 138,    // Set outer radius so wheel fits inside the background.
'lineWidth'   : 2,
'segments'    :         // Define segments including colour and text.
[
  {'fillStyle' : '#eae56f', 'text' : 'Segment 1'},
  {'fillStyle' : '#89f26e', 'text' : 'Segment 2'},
  {'fillStyle' : '#7de6ef', 'text' : 'Segment 3'},
  {'fillStyle' : '#e7706f', 'text' : 'Segment 4'},
  {'fillStyle' : '#0D56A6', 'text' : 'Segment 5'},
  {'fillStyle' : '#29c932', 'text' : 'Segment 6'}
],
'animation'    :        // Specify the animation to use.
{
  'type'       : 'spinToStop',
  'duration'   : 5,     // Duration in seconds.
  'spins'      : 10,    // Number of complete spins.
  // 'callbackFinished'  : 'alertPrize()'    // Alert to show prize won
}

});

$scope.wheelSpinning = false;


//Click handler for spin button.
function startSpin()
{
// Ensure that spinning can't be clicked again while already running.
if ($scope.wheelSpinning == false)
{
  spinWheel.animation.spins = 9;

  // Begin the spin animation by calling startAnimation on the wheel object.
  spinWheel.startAnimation();

  // Set to true so that power can't be changed and spin button re-enabled during
  // the current animation. The user will have to reset before spinning again.
  $scope.wheelSpinning = true;
}
}

// Function for the reset button.
function resetWheel()
{
spinWheel.stopAnimation(false);   // Stop the animation, false as parameter so does not call callback function.
spinWheel.rotationAngle = 0;      // Reset to false to power buttons and spin can be clicked again.
spinWheel.draw();                 // Call draw to render changes to the wheel.

$scope.wheelSpinning = false;     // Reset to false so spin can be clicked again.
$scope.$apply();
}

// Called when the spin animation has finished by the callback feature of the wheel
alertPrize = function()
{
// Get the segment indicated by the pointer on the wheel background which is at 0 degrees.
var winningSegment = spinWheel.getIndicatedSegment();

// Alert of selected segment text.
$ionicPopup.alert({
  title: 'Success',
  content: "You have won " + winningSegment.text + "!"
});

}

$scope.spinWheel = startSpin();

}]);
```

Comment: `spinWheel is not defined` is quite self explanatory...

Comment: Post your controller's full code

Comment: updated with the code from the controller @RishiTiwari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some research finally able to fix it. I changed the following in my controller

```
function startSpin()
{
    //...
}
```

and

```
function resetWheel()
{
    //
}
```

to

```
$scope.startSpin = function()
{
    //
}
```

and

```
$scope.resetWheel = function()
{
    //
}
```

then in my view was able to access both functions so

```
<button ng-click="startSpin()">Spin the Wheel</button>
```

and for the reset

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="resetWheel()">Reset</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

On using ng-click your application is not responding because the spinWheel.startSpin() method is not exposed to scope.

There are 2 ways to solve this

1. Expose the spinWheel object to your scope and put the method startSpin in the spinWheel object.

**Controller**

`$scope.spinWheel = {
    var startSpin = function() {
      //Code Here
    }
    var stopSpin = function() {
      //Code Here
    }
}`

2. Expose the controller as spin wheel in your HTML

`<div ng-controller = "PlayCtrl as spinWheel">
   <button onClick="spinWheel.startSpin()">Spin the Wheel</button>
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="spinwheel.resetWheel();">Reset</a>
</div>`

Answer (score 0):

In your above shared code your class spinWheel is not in scope, do something like below

```
 $scope.spinWheel= new Winwheel({
'numSegments' : 6,      // Specify number of segments.
'outerRadius' : 138,    // Set outer radius so wheel fits inside the background.
'lineWidth'   : 2,
'segments'    :         // Define segments including colour and text.
[
  {'fillStyle' : '#eae56f', 'text' : 'Segment 1'},
  {'fillStyle' : '#89f26e', 'text' : 'Segment 2'},
  {'fillStyle' : '#7de6ef', 'text' : 'Segment 3'},
  {'fillStyle' : '#e7706f', 'text' : 'Segment 4'},
  {'fillStyle' : '#0D56A6', 'text' : 'Segment 5'},
  {'fillStyle' : '#29c932', 'text' : 'Segment 6'}
],
'animation'    :        // Specify the animation to use.
{
  'type'       : 'spinToStop',
  'duration'   : 5,     // Duration in seconds.
  'spins'      : 10,    // Number of complete spins.
  // 'callbackFinished'  : 'alertPrize()'    // Alert to show prize won
}

});
```

Then use its function on your view the way you are using currently

Comment: Winheel is not defined

Comment: have you created any plunker..if not please create one , it will be easy for me to help you

Comment: thanks was able to fix with the help of my boss, specified it but cannot mark as the answer. i will create a plunker also so it can be better viewed.

Answer (score 0):

Just add following code instead of $scope.spinWheel = startSpin();

```
$scope.spinWheel ={
                       startSpin:startSpin,
                       resetWheel:resetWheel
                };
```

and instead of onClick="spinWheel.startSpin()"

```
ng-click="spinWheel.startSpin"
```

and instead of onClick="spinwheel.resetWheel();"

```
ng-click="spinWheel.resetWheel"
```

It will work.